# Planning an "almost" instant messaging system with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My website currently divides and displays messages in a conversation using PHP. I would like to implement jQuery into the messaging system and provide updates at intervals.

My biggest concern is bandwidth use. My workaround is to make a variable that stores a unix timestamp of the last message received from the sender. This variable will be sent to a script every x (lets say 30) seconds and the script will do a mysql count(*) for any records that have a newer timestamp than the one in the variable. If there is, another script would run to update the messages, if not it would simply keep checking at whatever intervals it is set to.

Can anyone provide any insight or suggestions while I start working on this? I really don't want to go beyond php/jquery unless it doesn't require a whole server.

Comment: You can do this by keeping an open connection to the browser and using SQL triggers to send new data on that connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/) tutorial will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hacky technique for doing "push" over http called [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

The idea is basically to have the server never close one of the http connections and use that to push more data to the client.  The pitfalls of this technique are that clients only open a limited number of simultaneous http connections to a given host and that the connection will eventually time out.  (The latter issue can be detected via  a heart-beat signal and the connection can be re-opened accordingly).

Comment: Also with this technology doesn't each user eat up a thread of execution on a server (ie much more resources) and does it work with load-balancing?